# How to set return value to mock object created from another mock object using unittest?

Tags: python, python-unittest

```
from connection_util import some_engine

class RecommendConversationsUsingOldAPI(BaseResource):

    def check_entitlement(self,msg_ids,usr_id, metadata):
            conn = some_engine.connect()
            some_list = conn.execute(something)
```

Unittest

```
@patch('module1.some_engine')  
def test_some_method(self, mockEngine):
        # some code.....
```

I can mock `some_engine`

```
@patch('module1.some_engine')
```

How do set `return_value` for `conn.execute()`?

Answer (score 0):

Manually created `Mock` object can be returned for `connect()`

```
 mock_connection = Mock()
 mock_connection.execute.return_value = [1,2,3,4]

 mockEngine.connect.return_value = mock_connection
```